# Why running "streamlit hello" returns an error in locally installed VSC?

Tags: visual-studio-code, error-handling, anaconda, streamlit

I'm relatively new to python/vsc/anaconda and trying to follow a tutorial (https://30days.streamlit.app/?utm_medium=oembed), I run into an error, that made me realise that my environment is a bit of a mess.

When launch VS code from my Windows taskbard and run "install streamlit" it work fine. But when I go to the vsc terminal and run "streamlit hello" as in the above tutorial, I get an error:

[This is the error when running streamlit hello on the local vsc](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NRPBA.png)

However, if I open Anaconda and launch VS code from there, I can install streamlit just as before (in the same .ipynb file, but when I run "streamlit hello" in the terminal, it works with no error.

[This time I try in VSC launched through Anaconda and it works fine](https://i.stack.imgur.com/57nlB.png).

This makes me believe that something is wrong with the VSC installed locally.

Therefore, my question is, why do I get the error when I run in the VSC outside Anaconda, and two, what is the best way to organize my environment given that this is for a data science project? Is there any benefit of having this local VSC installation or should I just uninstall it?

Thanks and feel free to ask if I need to clarify some more things.

After the initial error, I tried using the vsc in Anaconda and it worked without error. But I want to understand why I got the error in the first and what's the best way to organize my codding environment.